# fetch retry request (on failure)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, polyfills

I'm using browser's native [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for network requests. Also I am using the [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) polyfill for unsupported browsers.

However I need to retry in case the request fails. Now there is this npm package [whatwg-fetch-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch-retry) I found, but they haven't explained how to use it in their docs. Can somebody help me with this or suggest me an alternative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to try JS fetch() method in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60289882/how-to-try-js-fetch-method-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 30):

From the fetch docs :

```
fetch('/users')
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(function(data) {
          console.log('succeeded', data)
    }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('request failed', error)
    })
```

See that catch? Will trigger when fetch fails, you can fetch again there.
Have a look at the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) API.

Implementation example:

```js
function wait(delay){
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
}

function fetchRetry(url, delay, tries, fetchOptions = {}) {
    function onError(err){
        triesLeft = tries - 1;
        if(!triesLeft){
            throw err;
        }
        return wait(delay).then(() => fetchRetry(url, delay, triesLeft, fetchOptions));
    }
    return fetch(url,fetchOptions).catch(onError);
}
```

Edit 1: [as suggested by golopot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661731), p-retry is a nice option.

Edit 2: simplified example code.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm currently doing. But I'm looking for something like an additional optional 
{
   retry: 3, //max number of retries
   retryTimeout: 3000 //timeout between successive requests
}

Comment: I just updated the example with what I think should be a working version, you may need some tweak tough. Tell me if u want some comments in the code to make it clearer.

Comment: This is [needlessly complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: Thansk for pointing that out @BenjaminGruenbaum the code was pretty messy

Answer (score 10):

I recommend using some library for promise retry, for example [p-retry](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-retry).

Example:

```js
const pRetry = require('p-retry')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function fetchPage () {
  const response = await fetch('https://stackoverflow.com')

  // Abort retrying if the resource doesn't exist
  if (response.status === 404) {
    throw new pRetry.AbortError(response.statusText)
  }

  return response.blob()
}

;(async () => {
  console.log(await pRetry(fetchPage, {retries: 5}))
})()
```

Answer (score 10):

One can easily wrap `fetch(...)` in a loop and `catch` potential errors (fetch only rejects the returning promise on network errors and the alike):

```js
const RETRY_COUNT = 5;

async function fetchRetry(...args) {
  let count = RETRY_COUNT;
  while(count > 0) {
    try {
      return await fetch(...args);
    } catch(error) {
      // logging ?
    }

    // logging / waiting?

    count -= 1;
  }

  throw new Error(`Too many retries`);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't like recursion unless is really necessary. And managing an exploding number of dependencies is also an issue. Here is another alternative in typescript. Which is easy to translate to javascript.

```
interface retryPromiseOptions<T>  {
    retryCatchIf?:(response:T) => boolean, 
    retryIf?:(response:T) => boolean, 
    retries?:number
}

function retryPromise<T>(promise:() => Promise<T>, options:retryPromiseOptions<T>) {
    const { retryIf = (_:T) => false, retryCatchIf= (_:T) => true, retries = 1} = options
    let _promise = promise();

    for (var i = 1; i < retries; i++)
        _promise = _promise.catch((value) => retryCatchIf(value) ? promise() : Promise.reject(value))
           .then((value) => retryIf(value) ? promise() : Promise.reject(value));
    
    return _promise;
}
```

And use it this way...

```
retryPromise(() => fetch(url),{
    retryIf: (response:Response) => true, // you could check before trying again
    retries: 5
}).then( ... my favorite things ... )
```

I wrote this for the fetch API on the browser. Which does not issue a reject on a 500. And did I did not implement a wait. But, more importantly, the code shows how to use composition with promises to avoid recursion.

Javascript version:

```
function retryPromise(promise, options) {
    const { retryIf, retryCatchIf, retries } = { retryIf: () => false, retryCatchIf: () => true, retries: 1, ...options};
    let _promise = promise();

    for (var i = 1; i < retries; i++)
        _promise = _promise.catch((value) => retryCatchIf(value) ? promise() : Promise.reject(value))
           .then((value) => retryIf(value) ? promise() : Promise.reject(value));
    
    return _promise;
}
```

Javascript usage:

```
retryPromise(() => fetch(url),{
    retryIf: (response) => true, // you could check before trying again
    retries: 5
}).then( ... my favorite things ... )
```

EDITS: Added js version, added retryCatchIf, fixed the loop start.

Comment: For you its easy to translate to javascript, however for me everything you've written there looks exactly like javascript. Could you translate this to js for me and others like me?

Comment: @problemlow Ok, just because you asked nicely :^)

Answer (score 2):

Using both [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295995/1720199) and [Isidrock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46176314/1720199) answers and adding typescript types:

```
const MAX_NB_RETRY = 5;
const RETRY_DELAY_MS = 200;

export default async function fetchRetry(input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined) {
    let retryLeft = MAX_NB_RETRY;
    while (retryLeft > 0){
        try {
            return await fetch(input, init);
        }
        catch (err) { 
            await sleep(RETRY_DELAY_MS)
        }
        finally {
            retryLeft -= 1;
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`Too many retries`);
}

function sleep(delay: number){
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
}
```