# Google Vision API Occasionally Returns 404 Error

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch, http-status-code-404, google-cloud-vision

I'm having exactly the same intermittent 404 issue calling the API from a Google Apps Script as mentioned here:
[Javascript Fetch returns 404 occasionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55651169/javascript-fetch-returns-404-occasionally)

Should this be reported to Google for assessment and remediation?  If so, how?
Or is this just something they'll respond "deal with it".

```js
  var videoApiUrl = 'https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1/';

  var annotateUrl = videoApiUrl + 'videos:annotate?key=' + apiKey;  

  var testFile = DriveApp.getFileById('11MIdGHM0tYZ5o0p5QebD8uPELYGTntzZ');

  var testBlob = testFile.getBlob();
  var testBase64Bytes = Utilities.base64Encode(testBlob.getBytes());

  var JSON_REQ = XbuildJSONRequestVideoBase64(testBase64Bytes, 'PERSON_DETECTION');
  
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'payload': JSON_REQ
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(annotateUrl, options);
  var objName = JSON.parse(response);
```

Result:
404. That's an error.
The requested URL yadda-yadda was not found on this server.
That's all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to implement [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff).

GAS guru Bruce McPherson covered this topic on his site Desktop Liberation.

See post linked below:

[Backing off on rate limiting](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/database-abstraction-and-google-apps-script/backing-off-on-rate-limiting/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about exponential backoff.
I don't think it is a quota / resource issue.
My requests are single-threaded so I'm not hitting any of these published limits (https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/quotas).
And the error message I'm getting doesn't resemble any of the resource limit error messages documented.

Comment: @TomScheifler Exponential backoff can also be used to retry failed requests. So in that context it might be of use to you

Comment: agreed. But in this case, a simpler retry at a static interval (e.g. 10 seconds) seems to work since it is not caused by quota. 
So the original question, still stands. Is it worth reporting and how would I do that?