# Fetch data after 10 seconds if no result is returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app makes a fetch to a web service that can sometimes be slow to respond due to circumstances out of my control. It seems that if it gets stuck waiting for a response, the solution is to fetch for the data again. How would one make a function to fetch fetch for data every 10 seconds, and stop when the endpoint delivers a result?

Comment: Learn `Promises` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: This looks like a good use case for using observables.

Comment: Given the amount of detail in your question, how can you expect any more detail in an answer? As can be seen, all you'll end up with is a bunch of confusing suggestions that may (but most likely will not) be of use. Show us what you've tried when attempting to solve your question, and where ***specifically*** you've come unstuck. Vaguely asking for suggestions on SO will simply encourage down/close-votes.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175660/fetch-retry-request-on-failure

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript you can use `setInterval`

```
var myInterval = setInterval(tryToGetData, 10000); // Try to get data every 10 secs

function tryToGetData() {
  // Get your data here, preferably as a promise
  yourDataPromise.then((data) => {
    clearInterval(myInterval); // Stop trying to get data every 10 secs
    // Do stuff with 

  });
}
```

However a much better way is to retry the promise when it naturally fails, by trying to get the data again by catching the promise itself.

Comment: Without cancelling the previous attempt to "fetch" the data, this promises to be a confusing mess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timer that will fetch data every 10 seconds
and if the data is found, you will clear the timer so that data will not be fetch again

```
var data = setInterval(function(){
  // call fetch data function
  fetchData((err, data) => {
    if(data) {
      clearInterval(data);
    }
  })
}, 10000);  


function fetchData(cb) {
  // rightnow we are passing data '1' to the callback so the timer will run only once as data is fetched
  // try removing '1' and you will see that `fetchData` function is called on every 10 seconds
  cb(null, 1);
}
```

Comment: Supposing the previous attempt completes after 11 seconds? You didn't make any attempt to cancel it.

Comment: you can cancel the existing fetchData request before it fetches the data again
cancelExistingRequest();
fetchData((err, data) => {
    if(data) {
      clearInterval(data);
    }
  })