# Execute setInterval function without delay first time, but conditionally more times after delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout, setinterval

In my React Native app, I'm using `setInterval` to poll an API call every few seconds to achieve a certain goal, like this:

```
 this.timer = setInterval(() => this.doSomething(), 4000);
```

The problem is it only starts after 4 seconds. I have read other answers that suggest calling the function immediately and then calling `setInterval` to execute it again after a delay, but that is not working for me because what if the first call succeeds in achieving what I needed it to do? Then I don't want it to be called again, only once would have been enough.

How do I call it once, then if it fails I start polling it every 4 seconds?

Edit: Forgot to mention specifically that `this.doSomething` is an async function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch retry request (on failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175660/fetch-retry-request-on-failure)

Comment: *what if the first call succeeds in achieving what I needed it to do?* -- `clearInterval()`, just like you presumably call it already somewhere?

Comment: @user18309290 I am using axios library, but it's very much the same, thanks, I'll look into that to see if it can help me

Comment: I'd use a library that already implements retries--seems annoying to reimplement something that's a solved problem, especially when good alternatives exist.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree, but I always try to minimise adding new libraries for every small little issue I run into, especially for small issues like this. It seems so simple, there must be an easy native way of doing it, without cluttering my already big app with more packages.

Comment: @instanceof "Easy" depends on how well you want to do it. Of course it can be done "natively"; everything in a library is just code.

Comment: @DaveNewton That is very true, I agree completely, well said. I just enjoy doing it myself as well, I want to understand how it works and practice how to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the function first and then setInterval if it fails. You just need to return from the function whether it succeeded, and add an if statement before using setInterval.

```js
let timer;

function doSomething() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        // if success, return true
        console.log("Success")
        if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
        return true;
    } else {
        // if failed, return false
        console.log("Failed")
        return false;
    }
}

let result = doSomething()

if (!result) {
    timer = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
}
```

Async version:

```js
let timer;

async function doSomething() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        // if success, return true
        console.log("Success")
        if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
        return true;
    } else {
        // if failed, return false
        console.log("Failed")
        return false;
    }
}

doSomething().then(
    (result) => {
        if (!result) {
            timer = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks yes this is what I was thinking, but `doSomething` is an API call which means it is async, so this approach would not work exactly...

Comment: @instanceof I added an async version. Does that work?